# Catch child background threads within calling method in foreground thread

Tags: c#

I want to call a method once by a specified interval (e.g. 3 seconds), but I have problem catching exception within the calling method (e.g. Start) thrown by the called method (timer_Elapsed)

**Update**

```
public void Start()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(PingPeriod);  //System.Timers
        try
        {
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //I want to catch exception thrown by timer_Elapsed

        }

      //Logic here that keeps the method running 
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       throw new exception("Catch this exception please");
    }
```

**Update:**

Can anyone please confirm that the start() will NOT catch exception thrown from timer_Elapsed, or when trying to invoke timer_Elapsed if exception occurred.

Is there a better alternative, which can catch exception from a called method or get notified?

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This just isn't possible, the Elapsed event handler runs *later*, well after your Start() method has exited.  Furthermore, that event has the nasty habit of swallowing *all* exceptions without any diagnostic.

You'll need to handle exceptions within the event handler.  Certainly not easy to do.  Do consider using the System.Threading.Timer class instead.  At least your program will terminate when the callback throws an exception.

Comment: But I can catch exception within timer_Elapsed method.

Comment: But of course, why don't you?  Do log it somewhere so this isn't completely unobservable.

Comment: So can you confirm that the start() will NOT catch exception thrown from timer_Elapsed, or when trying to invoke timer_Elapsed.

Comment: Asked and answered.  You are looking for a time machine.  Going backwards in time is sorta possible in software.  Forward is a major problem.  Predicting the future is only claimed to be possible in financial code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the exception is thrown on a different execution context (thread) from the one that set up the timer.

You should handle any exceptions in your callback method. If you want your logic separated from your exception handling, simply create a separate method.

```
private void TimerElapsedCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle
    }
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    // logic goes here and can be agnostic of any exceptions it throws, if desired
}
```